# How to import specific methods in google cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, lodash

**index.ts**

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

import { includes } from "lodash-es";

export const isFruit = functions.https.onCall((_, __) => includes(["apple", "orange"], "apple"));
```

Now when ever I try to start firebase emulator `firebase emulators:start`. I get the following error.

> Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate
> manifest from function source: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of
> ES Module
> C:\Users_____\functions\node_modules\lodash-es\lodash.js from
> C:\Users_____\functions\lib\index.js not supported. Instead
> change the require of lodash.js in
> C:\Users_____\functions\lib\index.js to a dynamic import() which
> is available in all CommonJS modules.

Comment: You are using the correct format to import a specific method. However, have you tried installing Lodash-es Library? Can you try to install using this command 'npm i lodash-es'.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `lodash` instead of `lodash-es`

Run these commands

```bash
npm uninstall lodash-es @types/lodash-es
npm install lodash
npm install -D @types/lodash
```